# Vuejs v-model.trim skips spaces

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to write reactive fields with name without spaces, but there was a problem with `v-model.trim`, such code doesn't filter spaces, what's the problem?
My Vue page

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Name: {{title}}</span>
        <input type="text" v-model.trim="title">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            title:''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I enter "H e l l o", and I get it, but I want "Hello"

Comment: Please give an example what `title` contains, and what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent spaces in the input. You can prevent by using `@keydown.space.prevent`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      title: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>Name: {{title}}</span>
<input type="text" @keydown.space.prevent v-model="title"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim only filter spaces at start and end.If you want remove all spaces,you can use `const removeSpaces = (str)=>str.replace(/\s+/g,'')`